# Ember: How do you create a query that filters on the property of a belongsTo record?

Tags: ember.js, filter, belongs-to

I cannot find an answer to this - so, first time post:

Here are the models:

```
App.File = DS.Model.extend({
  toRender: DS.attr('boolean'),
  dataPoints: DS.hasMany('DataPoint')
});

App.DataPoint = DS.Model.extend({
  file: DS.belongsTo('File'),
  etc: DS.attr('number')
)};
```

I should be able to select only DataPoints where etc property = 123 using:

```
this.store.filter(App.DataPoint, { etc: 123 }, function (datapoint) {
  console.log(datapoint);
});
```

But how do I swap in a query to select only DataPoints where the File it belongsTo has a toRender property set to true?